# writing a second query based on results of the first - Not working

Tags: php, mysql

*MySQL will be upgraded later.

Preface: Authors can register in two languages and, for various additional reasons, that meant 2 databases. We realize that the setup appears odd in the use of multiple databases but it is more this abbreviated explanation that makes it seem so. So please ignore that oddity.

Situation:
My first query produces a recordset of authors who have cancelled their subscription. It finds them in the first database.

```
require_once('ConnString/FirstAuth.php');

mysql_select_db($xxxxx, $xxxxxx);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT auth_email FROM Authors WHERE Cancel = 'Cancel'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $xxxxxx) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
```

In the second db where they are also listed, (table and column names are identical) I want to update them because they cancelled. To select their records for updating, I want to take the first recordset, put it into an array, swap out the connStrings, then search using that array.

These also work.

```
$results = array();
do {
results[] = $row_Recordset1;
} while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));

print_r($results);
```

gives me an array. Array ( [0] => Array ( [auth_email] => renault@autxxx.com ) [1] => Array ( [auth_email] => rinaldi@autxxx.com ) [2] => Array ( [auth_email] => hemingway@autxxx.com )) ...so I know it is finding the first set of data.

Here's the problem: The query of the second database looks for the author by auth_email if it is 'IN' the $results array, but it is not finding the authors in the 2nd database as I expected. Please note the different connString

```
require_once('ConnString/SecondAuth.php');

mysql_select_db($xxxxx, $xxxxxx);
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT auth_email FROM Authors WHERE auth_email IN('$results')";
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $xxxxxx) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
```

The var_dump is 0 but I know that there are two records in there that should be found.
I've tried various combinations of IN  like {$results}, but when I got to "'$results'", it was time to ask for help. I've checked all the available posts and none resolve my problem though I am now more familiar with the wild goose population.

I thought that since I swapped out the connection string, maybe $result was made null so I re-set it to the original connString and it still didn't find auth_email in $results in the same database where it certainly should have done.

Further, I've swapped out connStrings before with positive results, so... hmmm...

My goal, when working, is to echo the Recordset2 into a form with a do/while loop that will permit me to update their record in the 2nd db. Since the var_dump is 0, obviously this below isn't giving me a list of authors in the second table whose email addresses appear in the $results array, but I include it as example of what I want use to start the form in the page.

```
do { 
    $row_Recordset2['auth_email_addr '];
} while($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2));
```

As always, any pointer you can give are appreciated and correct answers are Accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IN` clause excepts variables formated like this `IN(var1,var2,var3)`
You should use function to create a string, containing variables from this array.

```
//the simplest way to go
$string = '';

foreach($results as $r){
 foreach($r as  $r){
 $string .= $r.",";
 }
}

$string = substr($string,0,-1); //remove the ',' from the end of string
```

Its not tested, and obviously not the best way to go, but to show you the idea of your problem and how to handle it is this code quite relevant.

Now use `$string` instead of `$results` in query

Comment: This looks interesting and has triggered some thoughts. I'll look further and get back to you. And thank you @JTC

Comment: Hi @JTC, I keep messing with this because it looks right but it gives me Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array. I'm missing something, obviously

Comment: I just make an edit to comment, use this code, you have multidimensional array, if this does not work, show the array with `var_dump($results);`

Comment: That got it @JTC. Thanks for following up. You saved me from wasting more time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a db user that has access to both databases and tables, just use a cross database query to do the update

```
UPDATE
  mydb.Authors,
  mydb2.Authors
SET
  mydb.Authors.somefield = 'somevalue'
WHERE
  mydb.Authors.auth_email = mydb2.Authors.auth_email AND
  mydb2.Authors.Cancel= 'Cancel'
```

Comment: Hmm, your answer may actually speed things up in a different, unexpected way. Let me look at this and comment further later. Thanks @Patrick.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Patrick. I'm actually using both of your answers to resolve this and make it work.